# Show for any odd prime $p\geq 5,$ $(-3/p)=1$ or $ -1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

Show for any odd prime $$p\geq 5,$$
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right ) =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } p\equiv 1,-5\pmod{12} \\ 
-1& \text{ if } p\equiv -1,5\pmod{12}
\end{cases}$$

So far I have that

(1) Let $$p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$$ then $$p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$ to get
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right )=-\left ( \frac{p}{3} \right )=-\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )=-1$$

(2)Let $$p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$$ then $$p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$ to get
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right )=-\left ( \frac{p}{3} \right )=-\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )=1$$

(3)Let $$p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$$ then $$p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$ to get
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right )=\left ( \frac{p}{3} \right )=\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )=1$$

(4)Let $$p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$$ then $$p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$ to get
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right )=\left ( \frac{p}{3} \right )=\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )=-1$$

After solving CRT systems I get,
$$\left ( \frac{-3}{p} \right ) =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } p\equiv 5,-5\pmod{12} \\ 
-1& \text{ if } p\equiv 1,-1\pmod{12}
\end{cases}.$$

So I'm not sure where I'm messing up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In case (1), $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)\left(\dfrac{3}p\right)=1\left(\dfrac{p}3\right)=1\times1=1$

Comment: No :/ I saw that earlier but it doesn't clear anything up, but thank you for suggesting it. @ShubhrajitBhattacharya

Comment: Oh shoot. Now I'm confused. Are all my calculations messed up? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: hint $p=1,5$ mod $6$ because $0,2,4$ mod $6$ numbers are always even and $3$ mod $6$ numbers are divisible by $3$

Comment: In case (2), $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)\left(\dfrac{3}p\right)=1\left(\dfrac{p}3\right)=\left(\dfrac{2}3\right)=-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does the $$\left ( \frac{-1}{p} \right )=1$$ come from the fact that $$p\equiv 1(mod4)$$

Comment: Yes, $\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)=1$ if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ and $-1$ if $p\equiv3\pmod4$

Comment: I redid them and got (3)=1 and (4)=-1 @J.W.Tanner Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You messed up some calculations.  When $p\equiv1\pmod4$, $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)\left(\dfrac{3}p\right)=1\left(\dfrac p3\right)$,

so in those cases $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=1$ when $p\equiv1\pmod3$ and $\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=-1$ when $p\equiv2\pmod3$ .